# How can I navigate from an activity to another using Navigation Component and removing the first activity from the stack?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-navigation

In my app I have two activities (AuthenticationActivity and MainActivity), each one with a nav graph and a big flow of fragments. I've created an action to navigate from a fragment of the AuthenticationActivity's graph to the MainActivity but it does not remove the AuthenticationActivity from the stack even if I set 'popTo' to the Authentication graph id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finish authentication activity after navigate method:

```
button2.setOnClickListener {
        view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_addItemFragment_to_mainActivity)
        (activity as AuthenticationActivity).finish()
    }
```