# Navigate from a login activity to the main activity using the Navigation Editor

Tags: android

My app has two activities. One is the login activity and this is the activity that is shown when the user starts the app. After successfully signing in, I want to navigate to the main activity.

I have not been able to successfully do this using the navigation editor.

Here is the layout for my login activity:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph_login"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="450dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="201dp">


</fragment>
```

This is the navigation graph for the login activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/nav_graph_login"
/>
```

This is the layout of my main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph_main"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="450dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="201dp"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And the navigation graph for the main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/nav_graph_main"
            app:startDestination="@id/loginActivity">

</navigation>
```

I see nothing in the navigation editor where I can connect the login activity to the main activity.

Answer (score 1):

The navigation editor is to allow you to navigate to different `Fragments` within one `Activity`. Each activity will have it's own navigation component (as you have done). Launching your `MainActivity` from your login activity, and activity life-cycle, needs to be handled outside of this.

Comment: I'm don't believe that is true. Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54824838/how-can-i-navigate-from-an-activity-to-another-using-navigation-component-and-re

I believe I'm just doing something wrong with my fragments.

Comment: Android documentation says: "Note: The Navigation component is designed for apps that have one main activity with multiple fragment destinations. The main activity is associated with a navigation graph and contains a NavHostFragment that is responsible for swapping destinations as needed. In an app with multiple activity destinations, each activity has its own navigation graph." https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started I have seen associated videos around moving to a single activity such as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2k8x8V77CrU, it is the intended usage

Comment: Your question refers to using the navigation editor. Whilst it is possible to (mis-)use the API to move between fragments of different Activities, I don't believe the editor is designed to let you do that easily.