# Navigate from one activity to another with Navigation Component

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I am trying to navigate from one navigation graph (with the host fragment on the `LoginActivity`) to another navigation graph (with the host fragment on the `HomeActivity`). I know Google is advocating for single activity applications and thus I am only going to be using these two Activities (to keep it minimal).

My `login_navigation.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/nav_login">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_login"
        android:name="your.appname.LoginFragment"
        android:label="@string/login_menu"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_login_to_enterCellphone"
            app:destination="@id/login_enter_cellphone"
            app:popUpTo="@id/nav_login" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/login_enter_cellphone"
        android:name="your.appname.LoginEnterCellphoneFragment"
        android:label="@string/enter_cellphone_fragment_label"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login_enter_cellphone" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_enter_cellphone_to_enterOTPFragment"
            app:destination="@id/enterOTPFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/login_enter_cellphone" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/enterOTPFragment"
        android:name="your.appname.EnterOTPFragment"
        android:label="@string/enter_otp_label"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_enter_o_t_p" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_enterOTPFragment_to_main_navigation"
            app:destination="@id/main_navigation"
            app:launchSingleTop="false" />
    </fragment>
    <include app:graph="@navigation/main_navigation" />
</navigation>
```

And `main_navigation.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/nav_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name="your.appname.HomeFragment"
        android:label="Home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
        android:name="your.appname.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="@string/profile_menu"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" />
</navigation>
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54825254/4232765) and implemented it as follows

```
private fun navigateToHomeActivity() {
    val action = EnterOTPFragmentDirections.actionEnterOTPFragmentToMainNavigation()
    findNavController().navigate(action)
    (activity as LoginActivity).finish() <-- later commented out
}
```

but it gives me the following error `E/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() rootView is null`

If I comment out the above line the error goes away but it only replaces the current fragment with the `HomeFragment`.

How do I navigate to another Activity so that the source Activity is removed (Can't navigate back to it) and the Destination Activity is used?

Comment: I ended up using `val intent = Intent(activity, HomeActivity::class.java)` and `startActivity(intent)` but I really want to use the Navigation Component.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can define 2 navigation graphs:

- `ActivityA` with navigation `Graph A`
- `ActivityB` with navigation `Graph B`

In the `GraphA` you can define a destination to start `ActivityB`

```
<!-- Graph A -->
<navigation 
   ....
   <activity
        android:id="@+id/activityB"
        android:name=".ActivityB"
        ...>

        <argument
            .... />

    </activity>

</navigation>
```

Then you can navigate to that activity ( = `startActivity(intent)`)  using it like a destination:

```
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.activityB);
```

More info [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-migrate#add).

Comment: What about navigation back? should navigateUp() work than ?