# Can navigation component be used from activity to activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

I need to navigate from my Login activity to my Home activity and I know this is discouraged but this is what I need to do for a project. The thing is, all the examples I see work with fragments. So how can I do that when person clicks on a button?

I added this to my login activity but I can't really link it in my nav graph:

```
binding.btnLogin.setOnClickListener {
       Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate(R.id.homeActivity)
}
```

I also need the app to close instead of go back to the previous activity which would be the login once I am at home ... any advice would be very helpful since this is my first time working with navigation.

Comment: I don't think the app "just closes". See the "Run" tab in AndroidStudio.
I think there is an exception.

Comment: @kirkadev oh i explained it better, i meant i want the app to close not that it does

Comment: I guess, what you need is this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62215512/1992823

Comment: show the XML and the navigation graph of LoginActivity

Answer (score -1):

You need to place the object in an intent and pass it like below.

```
void startMyActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, "HomeActivity")
    intent.putExtra("Navigate", myNavigationClass);
    startActivity(intent);
{
```

Then in home activity

```
   myNavigationClass = (typeCast) intent.getExtra("Navigate);
```

And for arriving home, closing the app just add

```
System.Exit(0);
```